# Generating sequential number based on a condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Thanks in advance for your support,

My xslt should generate the following xml format during execution,

```
<offers_list>
 <offer_info>
        <offer-id>4001</offer-id>
        <offer-counter>1</offer-counter>
 <offer_info>
 <offer_info>
        <offer-id>4897</offer-id>
        <offer-counter>2</offer-counter>
 <offer_info>
 <offer_info>
        <offer-id>3001</offer-id>
        <offer-counter>0</offer-counter>
 <offer_info>
 <offer_info>
        <offer-id>4567</offer-id>
        <offer-counter>3</offer-counter>
 <offer_info>
 <offer_info>
        <offer-id>1001</offer-id>
        <offer-counter>0</offer-counter>
 <offer_info>
</offers_list>
```

I have finished almost everything but how to generate a sequence counter in `<offer-counter>` tag based on condition ? The condition is, if offer-id value ranges from 4000 to 5000, increment the value.

Please advice

Comment: Is this the XML _output_ or _input_? If you have "almost finished everything", why not show us the existing XSLT code?

Comment: Hi, This is output xml, still the below solutions are not working for me, any help ? I have edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xsl:number`, for example:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="4000 &lt;= offer-id and offer-id &lt; 5000">
        <xsl:number count="offer_info[4000 &lt;= offer-id and offer-id &lt; 5000]"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

*The above works for XSLT 1.0 and 2.0.*

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide enough information, but I made a few guesses. Your XML is not well-formed because the `offer_info` elements are never closed. I used the following input:

**XML Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<offers_list>
 <offer_info>
        <offer-id>4001</offer-id>
 </offer_info>
 <offer_info>
        <offer-id>4897</offer-id>
 </offer_info>
 <offer_info>
        <offer-id>3001</offer-id>
 </offer_info>
 <offer_info>
        <offer-id>4567</offer-id>
 </offer_info>
 <offer_info>
        <offer-id>1001</offer-id>
 </offer_info>
</offers_list>
```

**Stylesheet**

The crucial part of the stylesheet, apart from an identity template is:

```
<xsl:when test="4000 le xs:integer(offer-id) and xs:integer(offer-id) le 5000">
  <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::offer-id[4000 le xs:integer(.) and xs:integer(.) le 5000]) + 1"/>
</xsl:when>
```

The first line tests whether the `offer-id` value is in between 4000 and 5000 (or exactly one of those numbers). To allow a comparison, the string value of `offer-id` must be cast to an `xs:integer` type. Then, all preceding `offer-id` elements that satisfy the condition are counted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="offer_info">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <offer-counter>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="4000 le xs:integer(offer-id) and xs:integer(offer-id) le 5000">
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::offer-id[4000 le xs:integer(.) and xs:integer(.) le 5000]) + 1"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </offer-counter>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<offers_list>
   <offer_info>
      <offer-id>4001</offer-id>
      <offer-counter>1</offer-counter>
   </offer_info>
   <offer_info>
      <offer-id>4897</offer-id>
      <offer-counter>2</offer-counter>
   </offer_info>
   <offer_info>
      <offer-id>3001</offer-id>
      <offer-counter>0</offer-counter>
   </offer_info>
   <offer_info>
      <offer-id>4567</offer-id>
      <offer-counter>3</offer-counter>
   </offer_info>
   <offer_info>
      <offer-id>1001</offer-id>
      <offer-counter>0</offer-counter>
   </offer_info>
</offers_list>
```